How to format a text in blazor
Hi guys I'm creating a new project in blazor and I'm trying to format a text before using in in my html, the way i'm trying to do it is by using a replace, my main problem is that i can add a break line
this is the function that I'm using
public string gLInjectionStatusFormattedText (string? rawText) {
        var text = rawText?.Replace("- Valve:", "\n Valve:")
            .Replace("{CompletionAnalysisResults.troubleshooting_data.cont_gaslift_cmpl_inject_status.ref_data.current_op_valve_description}", "Weatherford RO-1 5/32 (THC)")
            .Replace("- Mandrel number:", "\n Mandrel number:")
            .Replace("{CompletionAnalysisResults.troubleshooting_data.cont_gaslift_cmpl_inject_status.ref_data.current_op_valve_mand_num}", "8")
            .Replace("- Meas Depth:", "\n Meas Depth:")
            .Replace("{CompletionAnalysisResults.troubleshooting_data.cont_gaslift_cmpl_inject_status.ref_data.current_op_valve_depth}", "4833.0 feet")
            .Replace("{CompletionAnalysisResults.troubleshooting_data.cont_gaslift_cmpl_inject_status.ref_data.valve_status_summary}", "The deepest possible injection depth for this well is 4833.0 feet (MD) at current operating conditions.")
            .Replace("Valve Status Summary:", "Valve Status Summary:");

        return text ?? "";
    }

and I'm using it in the html (blazor) like this
<div Class="d-flex flex-column gap-4">
     <div Class="d-flex  gap-4">
        @getSummaryStatusColor(summaryStatus.GLInjectionStatus)
        <div>GL Injection Status:</div>
     </div>
     <p>@gLInjectionStatusFormattedText(summaryStatus.GLInjectionText)</p>                           
</div>

where summaryStatus.GLInjectionText is a string that i get from a db
I would like my text to look like this
This well is injecting at its designed operating point:

Valve: Weatherford RO-1 5/32 (THC)
Mandrel number: 6
Meas Depth: 4833.0 feet  
Valve Status Summary: The deepest possible injection depth for this well is 4833.0 feet (MD) at current operating conditions.
 
Lift gas injection is from an ORIF valve in mandrel number 6 at 4833.0 feet and has an estimated flow rate of 453.292 MCF/day.

But Instead of that in my html appears like this:
This well is injecting at its designed operating point: Valve: Weatherford RO-1 5/32 (THC) Mandrel number: 8 Meas Depth: 4833.0 feet &nbsp; Valve Status Summary: The deepest possible injection depth for this well is 4833.0 feet (MD) at current operating conditions.

Is there any way i can achieve this?

By default, HTML neglect newline characters \n and whitespace.
First solution
you can put your text between <pre></pre> which tell the HTML Engine to render the text as it is.
<div Class="d-flex flex-column gap-4">
     <div Class="d-flex  gap-4">
        @getSummaryStatusColor(summaryStatus.GLInjectionStatus)
        <div>GL Injection Status:</div>
     </div>
     <p><pre>@gLInjectionStatusFormattedText(summaryStatus.GLInjectionText)</pre></p>                           
</div>

second solution
you can change your function to return MarkupString instead of normal string which give you the power to write row HTML Tags and you can use <br> tag to get break line even more you can style part of your text with colors and other markup or whatever you want
public MarkupString gLInjectionStatusFormattedText(string? rawText)
{
    var text = rawText?.Replace("- Valve:", "<br>Valve:")
        .Replace("{CompletionAnalysisResults.troubleshooting_data.cont_gaslift_cmpl_inject_status.ref_data.current_op_valve_description}", "Weatherford RO-1 5/32 (THC)")
        .Replace("- Mandrel number:", "<br>Mandrel number:")
        .Replace("{CompletionAnalysisResults.troubleshooting_data.cont_gaslift_cmpl_inject_status.ref_data.current_op_valve_mand_num}", "8")
        .Replace("- Meas Depth:", "<br>Meas Depth:")
        .Replace("{CompletionAnalysisResults.troubleshooting_data.cont_gaslift_cmpl_inject_status.ref_data.current_op_valve_depth}", "4833.0 feet")
        .Replace("{CompletionAnalysisResults.troubleshooting_data.cont_gaslift_cmpl_inject_status.ref_data.valve_status_summary}", "The deepest possible injection depth for this well is 4833.0 feet (MD) at current operating conditions.")
        .Replace("Valve Status Summary:", "<br>Valve Status Summary:");

    return new(text ?? "");
}

using one of those method should solve your problem
take a look at

HTML <br> Tag
HTML <pre> Tag


the  approach makes the label  get printed in the html instead of creating a new break line, is there any reason?

Yeah when using only  the tag gets printed instead of creating a new br in any case the  approach was very useful and its what i needed, thank you so much!

I don't know how Blazor work, but it seems that it add escape mechanism for <br> and alter the letters < and > and change it with The character entity for security ... any way, happy to help you

@AngelGabrielChableConcepcio if you like to use <br>, you need to cast your string to  MarkupString class. As explained in this answer.

@AngelGabrielChableConcepcio No, don't do that.  It mights seem like an easy solution right now, but it forces a font change, which might be frustrating later.  You should just replace '\n' with '' and then make sure to cast to (MarkupString) in your markup.

@Bennyboy1973 if he uses the MarkupString he should be sure that the rowText is a safe string. Because if it comes from user's input it could lead to security vulnerability cross-site scripting ... if he knows that his string is safe because it has written by him or by any other trusted member then both of the approaches are trivially easy
